# ClamAV cannot access files

Tags: clamav

I've a server (CentOS 7) with ClamAV installed. clamdscan is running every 12 hours and for some files, I'm always getting the following message:

```
ClamAV has failed to run. The return error message was: An error occurred.

WARNING: /var/www/html/data/durchfhren.pdf: Can't access file

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8460865
Engine version: 0.103.2
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 20.110 sec (0 m 20 s)
Start Date: 2021:08:26 11:23:38
End Date: 2021:08:26 11:23:58
```

It looks like ClamAV tries to scan files that doesn't exist. The file is named "durchführen.pdf", but ClamAV tries to scan "durchfhren.pdf" It looks like ClamAV is having any problems scanning files with umlauts.

Is anyone having an idea what causes this issue or how I can solve it?

Comment: Can you provide the filesystem type you're using that the path `/var/www/html/data` is on?

Comment: @MatthewIfe The filesystem type is ext4

Comment: Can you run `stat /var/www/html/data/durchführen.pdf` and provide the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have special permission seems SELinux permission, it related to size or maxdeep search configuration in clamdscan.conf
Configuration sample:

StreamMaxLength 3000M

MaxScanSize 3000M

MaxFileSize 3000M

Comment: We're using CentOS. So SELinux is enabled but there's no "clamdscan.conf" file in the system. So I guess it's using the default configuration.